# Discard blanks in datastage

Tags: datastage, identity-column, transformer-model, blank-line

I have a Datastage job which takes the data from a file to a Dataset and for a column I would like to make a transformation in order to exclude the rows where that columns has no value:
For example I use in the transfomer the following rule where I put 0 everytime I find no value in the column lcvInstalmentOriginalStr, but I need this row to be discarded from the begining.

If lcvInstalmentOriginalStr <> "" Then StringToDecimal(lcvInstalmentOriginalStr)  Else 0

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a condition within a transformer stage (for example) to put just those rows on the output link (to the Dataset) that hold data.

The condition could look like this

```
lcvInstalmentOriginalStr <> ""
```